# Request to change tag name odoo10 to odoo-10

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Maybe it is just unimportant, but I think the tag [odoo10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo10) should be changed to [odoo-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo-10), because all other [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) tags have the same format except this one.

Comment: consistency is holy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems reasonable. And since there's only 16 questions tagged with it, this (retagging) can be done manually relatively easily.

Comment: I'll refrain from editing 'till we get some sort of community consensus.

Comment: So there is no chance to just rename the tag? There has to be done more (new tag, retagging, deleting old tag)?

Comment: Apparently moderators can change a tag's name.